# change root node in rpart [r]

Tags: r, tree, rpart

I am building a model to detect perturbances in a dataset using rpart.  below is a simple code:

```
model1 = rpart(OA~I0+IA,data=data,method="class",control = rpart.control(minsplit = 20, minbucket=1))
```

The resultant is a tree with "I0" as root node.  Is there a way I can generate a tree by fixing the root node to "IA"?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? You could simply fit trees in a 2 stage process. 0A~IA then 0A~IO using only subsets of the data from the previous tree's splits.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Bruce.  It made sense to use IA as root node than I0 (intuitively).  I actually developed a tree by hand which works well with IA as root node.  Therefore, I wanted to see if I can force rpart to get my result.  I will try your method.  How do I subset the data after the first split?  Shouldn't I use the same data?

Comment: You do use the same data but subset it based on the split the first model made. ie. the split is at IA <=5 on the first tree. Then build 2 versions of the 2nd tree... 0A~IO where IA <= 5 and OA~IO where IA > 5.